# django ORM AND-lookups on ManyToMany

Tags: python, django

How do I implement AND-lookups on Q() of the same field.

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    name = models.ManyToManyField(Type)

class Type(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField()
```

I tried:

```
Foo.objects.filter(Q(name__type='any'), Q(name__type='some'))
```

and

```
Foo.objects.filter(Q(name__type='any') & Q(name__type='some'))
```

However they both deliver empty querysets.

I am aware, that this will work:

```
Foo.objects.filter(name__type='any').filter(name__type='some')
```

However when creating more complex queries where `Q1`, `Q2`, `Q3` are `Q()` objects then

```
Foo.objects.filter(Q1).filter(Q2).filter(Q3)
```

could deliver different results than

```
Foo.objects.filter(Q2).filter(Q3).filter(Q1)
```

due to the order in which the filter is applied.

UPDATE:
I realized that this AND query works, as the modelField is not `ManyToMany` but rather `CharField`:

```
Type.objects.filter(Q(type__icontains='some') & Q(type__icontains='thing'))
```

So making an AND-Query only does not work on the ManyToMany-Relations.

Comment: what is the type of `name` in your example ?

Comment: please see my edited question above.

Comment: `Foo.objects.filter(Q(name__type='any') & Q(name__type='some'))` - if this returns an empty queryset, then you need to look at the data - it is very likely that there is no `FOO` object which have both `any` and `some` associated.

Comment: The queryset with both `any` and `some` definitely exist. Because when I do `Foo.objects.filter(name__type='any').filter(name__type='some')` i get a queryset with several results.

Answer (score 2):

The `filter` is already an **AND** lookup. Usually you will want to use `Q()` queries to compose **OR** lookups. I'm saying that because with **AND** lookups there are other ways to compose dynamic queries for example.

It's expected that the following query would return an empty queryset:

```
Foo.objects.filter(Q(name__type='any') & Q(name__type='some'))
```

Because either `Type` instance is named "any" or "some" -- it cannot be named both at the same time, so the queryset will always be empty.

But the syntax is correct. You can use it to join multiple **AND** lookup expressions (as long as they are filtering different fields, otherwise you may end up with an empty queryset). Because the filter is applied to each row in the database.

Another way to create complex and dynamic filter (using **AND** lookup) is using a dictionary:

```
params = {
  'first_name': 'foo',
  'last_name': 'bar'
}

if condition:
    params['email'] = 'foo@bar.com'

Foo.objects.filter(**params)
```

Comment: thank you very much for elaborating. How would I proceed to write this filter then? Please also see my comment above in my answer, as I realized that making such AND-Queries works for `CharFields` but not `ManyToMany`.

Answer (score 0):

As Victor Freitas already explained, it is not possible that a field can have two values ​​in the same record, but  since your relationship is a many-to-many, there can be several records and therefore the two values ​​can exist for the same field, but to make this query you must use the OR operator:

```
Foo.objects.filter(Q(name__type='any') | Q(name__type='some'))
```

Comment: This does not help at all, as it delivers either or or both but not exclusively both.